# Numpy indexing takes minutes on a large matrix

Tags: numpy

I have a dictionary with about 10 keys, one key is mapped to an a numpy array of 10000000 timestamps, the other keys are mapped to a numpy multidimensional arrays of shape [10000000, 30, 3] each.

I want to sort all arrays according to the timestamps:

```
sortorder = np.argsort(d['timestamp']) # takes 1 second to complete
for k in d.keys(): # This loops takes 6 minutes to complete
  d[k] = d[k][sortorder]
```

The sorting is very fast (one second), but the indexing takes a very long time. What is the reason for that, and can I do anything to make it faster?

Comment: what is `d`? do you have example data?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: `d` is the dictionary I mentioned. One can just create random data but watch out for your memory limits.

Comment: And how much memory do **you** have?

Comment: 16GB. do you suggested it may be slow due to memory limits?

Comment: Yes. Each array is 6+ GB in size. So your OS has no chance but to write all remaining arrays to swap.